# Why is Console showing js code even though I don't have it in seperate file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wanted to trigger some jquery action on an element but got an error. Console shows that here is an error:

[image]

But the thing is that I don't have this chunk of code in my js file at all..

My js:

```
    //    });
    //});
    
    
    //$('document').ready(function () {
    //    $('#tableT').DataTable({
    //        "order": [[3, "desc"]]
    //    });
    //});
    
    $('document').ready(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });

// more code here..
```

Why does the console show js code which not exist in my js.file?
Btw document.ready function is not working (all jquery sources are linked properly), I noticed that this chunk of code is not shown in Console at all.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a simple caching issue.

Comment: Cached? Or it could be dynamically added from another source in the page?

Comment: What is the name of your custom js file? Site.js?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes, Site.js

Comment: @mustafa00, this means that this piece of code is added dynamically, by another piece of code from another js file. Is it cms?

Comment: is your project local, or on the server? can you link to the site?

Comment: it's on my local server, it's not cms

Comment: I clered all cookies and other cache memory elements and it works now. Btw it's strange

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov no plugins. What I tried to implement in my code now was bootstrap toast to generate push notifications. And that's it

Comment: One more thing I noticed now: I added image to navbar with code: ```<img src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" width="60" height="60" class="d-inline-block" alt="" loading="lazy">``` As you see loading is lazy. May this cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `ctrl+shift+r` it will clear cache and reload the changes.

Comment: I reloaded, as you advised, but I uncommented other part of my code, compile the app and again the same, my js file is not loaded completely as it shoul be

Comment: Try this using chrome. Open console then right click on refresh button, you will find 3 options and then click on 3rd option "Empty cache and Hard Reload" or the above approach.